# How can you create a dynamic link to a workflow initiation form in a workflow-based e-mail?

Tags: workflow, workflow-variable, initiation-form

Process:

1. User Creates Item
2. Admin receives "approve this" e-mail with a dynamic link
3. Admin selects dynamic link in e-mail
4. Admin is taken to initiation form of second approval workflow
5. Admin selects approval check box, hits OK, workflow updates status and enters log info
6. Everyone is happy

This was easy in MOSS - just create a dynamic hyperlink: {Site URL}/Workflows/{Workflow Name}/{Workflow Initiation Form Page}?List={List ID}&ID={Item ID}

In SP2010, it seems to demand a different style: {Site URL}/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={List ID}&ID={Item ID}**&TemplateID={Template ID}**

The Template ID changes whenever the workflow is edited - which makes this whole dynamic process just a little less dynamic. I can't find a variable that matches Template ID anywhere in the new Workflow Context menu - and so no way around having a more formal change management process when it comes to these particular workflows.

Does anyone know of a way to get a dynamic variable for that Template ID?

Comment: This is also driving me nuts.. do you have already found a solution to this topic? Thanks and kind regards
Fabian Edit: I got a solution which works for myself.. Maybe it will help you to get your solution work:
Instead of using an (unexisting?) dynamic variable for template id value, I took the feature ID which is listed in the workflow feature properties. This ID seems not to change and fits my requirements.

Comment: why don't you start a workflow at item creation, then create a task for the admin, with an email notification ?

Comment: @Fabian - Does that end up looking like this? {Site URL}/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={List ID}&ID={Item ID}&FeatureID={Feature ID}

Comment: I have a suspicion that Microsoft made this change as a way of "resolving" a separate issue where designer doesn't always "take" your latest change to a workflow because it's reading from localcache. This no-longer-dyamic URL plus the new requirement to Publish a workflow, I assume, makes it much more reliable that SharePoint is going to run the latest and greatest.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a dynamic link? If you setup first workflow to fire off on new item created you already have "Current Item" in workflow that you can include in email to Approve. Than have second workflow that fires off when item is modified and status is set to Approved. This way you don't need custom form or dynamic links.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a workflow local variable on your first workflow to contain the template ID for the second workflow, and then use that to build your approval link?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to capture Template ID as a variable.

Comment: When that said workflow is edited, if you can't write the Template ID to a list or anywhere your other workflow can pick it up, it sounds like you may have to rethink your workflow design.